# What type of terminal is this

Tags: identification, terminal, wire-terminals, crimp

[image: The mystery crimp terminal...]

Okay, simple yet seemingly impossible question here... What type of terminal is this? It looks like exactly what we need, but I found the image on an advert for the shrink-wrap shown in the picture. The company don't know what it's called, none of the engineers I have asked have known, but if this terminal does what I believe it does (essentially 'lasso' a pole) it would save us SO much fabrication.

I have tried reverse image searches and googling every permutation of its description I can think of. Any help GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Ask at a garage. It looks like an unusually flimsy clamp for a car battery terminal.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: It isn't particularly flimsy, it just isn't one that's made of lead like most of them used to be.

Comment: As per below @DaveTweed, any idea where I could source one like this? I can't find a single similar one on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "battery terminal clamp". If you search using that phrase, you'll find thousands of possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those possibilities look/work anything like what's pictured (at least not in the first 30 pages of google...) - all looking like some permutation of https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/user/products/large/+ve_M8_Stud.jpg - that is to say, a lateral bolt squeezing together two ends of an almost-complete circle. They are also all quite substantial in both height and thickness. 

Due to size constraints of our installation, it's not possible to get anywhere near the terminals with one of those, where as a terminal like the one pictured would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/b/standard-ignition-5753/battery-accessories-16452/battery-cable-12835/97f343b1aaa1/standard-ignition-battery-cable/a66t/5791439/2004/honda/accord?pos=4)

Looks like it would fit the bill - all the cables with this type of clamp seem to be Honda-specific.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a battery clamp, and probably made to the OEM drawing.

Maybe you could use some variation of a [ground clamp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Blackburn-Bronze-Ground-Clamp-1-2-1-in-J-B1-25/202907605), perhaps with shorter screws substituted.

[image]